# Range of Week instead of be putting dates

Tags: oracle

I have below query but instead of to be putting range of week like '22-OCT-2012 AND 28-OCT-2012' I woulk to put a code like CurrentWeek -2 or CurrentWeek-1, that will avoid to edit the query every week that I need to run it.
Do you know how make this?

tHANKS
LD

```
    SELECT WO.USER_6 AS STYLE
 ,SUM (CASE WHEN (OPERATION.STATUS ='C' AND OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN '22-OCT-2012' AND '28-OCT-2012') THEN OPERATION.RUN_HRS ELSE 0 END) WEEK43
 ,SUM (CASE WHEN (OPERATION.STATUS ='C' AND OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN '29-OCT-2012' AND '04-NOV-2012') THEN OPERATION.RUN_HRS ELSE 0 END) WEEK44
FROM WORK_ORDER WO, OPERATION
WHERE  WO.BASE_ID = OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
AND WO.Lot_ID = Operation.Workorder_Lot_ID
        AND WO.Sub_ID = Operation.Workorder_Sub_ID
        AND WO.Split_ID = Operation.Workorder_Split_ID
AND WO.TYPE ='W'
AND WO.WAREHOUSE_ID ='MEX-04'
AND OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN '22-OCT-2012'  AND '04-NOV-2012'
AND OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID IN ('171-4','171-ADD','171-3' ,'BAMEX-SEWCONC','BAMEX-SEWPATC')
AND OPERATION.RUN > 0
GROUP BY
WO.USER_6
```

Comment: what do u mean by `CurrentWeek -2 or CurrentWeek-1` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question then u can use this to pass the current week days like this

```
SUM (CASE WHEN (OPERATION.STATUS ='C' AND OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN to_char(trunc(sysdate),'DD-MON-YYYY')  and to_char(trunc(sysdate)-6,'DD-MON-YYYY')) THEN OPERATION.RUN_HRS ELSE 0 END) WEEK43
```

Hope this help u

Answer (score 0):

In this case I will use `trunc` function:

```
currentweek will be trunc(sysdate,'D') 
current_week - 1 will be trunc(sysdate,'D') - 7
current week - 2 will be trunc(sysdate,'D') - 2 * 7
```

Attention this will give first day of week sunday. If you want monday you should and one day:

```
current week - 2 will be trunc(sysdate,'D') - 2 * 7 + 1
```

**UPDATE:**
Frank is right, the behavior on first day of week depends on NLS_TERITORY

```
alter session set NLS_TERRITORY ='UNITED KINGDOM';
select trunc(sysdate,'D') from dual;
05-11-2012

alter session set NLS_TERRITORY ='AMERICA';
select trunc(sysdate,'D') from dual;
04-11-2012
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a little bit more complicated than that. Whether trunc(..., 'D') gives sunday or monday as first day of week depends on the NLS settings.

Comment: Hello all, maybe not explain my problem on the best way, but what I need is to replace this code: BETWEEN '22-OCT-2012' AND '28-OCT-2012')  to for example WeeK43 using a method that in case I run this query next week is not necessary to updated the query, it should run based in a previous week. Thanks

Comment: yes, will be `between trunc(sysdate,'D') -2*7 and trunc(sysdate,'D') - 7`

Comment: Hello Ghita, I have a new question, since previous week not work ok. I use OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE between trunc(sysdate,'D') -1*7 and trunc(sysdate,'D') -1)  instead of OPERATION.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN '19-NOV-2012' AND '25-NOV-2012')  but does not work perfect, do you know what is the issue?